# how to add multiple selected option value in list of one-to-many relationship class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

This is "Item" class

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace RandApp.Models
{
    public class Item : BaseEntity
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Item Photo")]
        public string ItemPhoto { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Item Type")]
        public string ItemType { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Item Category")]
        public string ItemCategory { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Item Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Item Colors")]
        public List<ItemColors> Color { get; set; } = new List<ItemColors>();
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Item Size")]
        public List<ItemSizes> Size { get; set; } = new List<ItemSizes>();
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Item Material Type")]
        public string MaterialType { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Designed For")]
        public string DesignedFor { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Item Price")]
        public double Price { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Item Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is "ItemColors" and "ItemSizes" classes

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace RandApp.Models
{
    public class ItemColors : BaseEntity
    {
        public string ItemColor { get; set; }
        public int? ItemId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ItemId")]
        public Item Item { get; set; }
    }
}

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace RandApp.Models
{
    public class ItemSizes : BaseEntity
    {
        public string ItemSize { get; set; }
        public int? ItemId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ItemId")]
        public Item Item { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and This is the view

```
@model RandApp.Models.Item

<h4>Add Item</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="CreateItem" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.ItemPhoto" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="file" name="ItemPhoto" class="form-control-file" onchange="SetValue(this)" />
                <input asp-for="@Model.ItemPhoto" hidden />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.ItemPhoto" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.DesignedFor" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="@Model.DesignedFor" class="form-control">
                    <option value="" selected>Select Designed For</option>
                    @foreach (var desigendFor in Enum.GetValues(typeof(RandApp.Enums.DesignedFor)))
                    {
                        <option val="@desigendFor" value="@desigendFor.ToString()">@desigendFor</option>
                    }
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.DesignedFor" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.ItemCategory" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="@Model.ItemCategory" class="form-control">
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.ItemCategory" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.ItemType" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="@Model.ItemType" class="form-control">
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.ItemType" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.MaterialType" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="@Model.MaterialType" class="form-control">
                    <option value="" selected>Select Material Type</option>
                    @foreach (var materialType in Enum.GetValues(typeof(RandApp.Enums.MaterialType)))
                    {
                        <option value="@materialType.ToString()">@materialType</option>
                    }
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
                <input id="otherMaterialInp" asp-for="@Model.MaterialType" class="form-control" style="display:none; margin-top:8px" placeholder="Enter Material Type" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.MaterialType" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Color" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="@Model.Color" multiple class="form-control">
                    @foreach (var color in Enum.GetValues(typeof(RandApp.Enums.ItemColor)))
                    {
                        <option value="@color.ToString()">@color.ToString()</option>
                    }
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
                <input id="otherColorInp" asp-for="@Model.Color" class="form-control" style="display:none; margin-top:8px" placeholder="Enter Item Color" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Color" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Size" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="@Model.Size" multiple class="form-control">
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Size" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Price" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.Price" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Price" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <textarea asp-for="@Model.Description" class="form-control"></textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" asp-for- class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

So this is what I want to do: I want to select multiple color and size and add them values in Item.Color and Item.Size lists, but when I try it, I get empty lists in controller. There is controller

```
// POST Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateItem(Item item, IFormFile ItemPhoto)
{
     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         return View();
     }

     var path = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "assets", ItemPhoto.FileName);
     var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
     await ItemPhoto.CopyToAsync(stream);
     item.ItemPhoto = ItemPhoto.FileName;

     await _itemRepo.CreateAsync(item);
     stream.Close();
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

How can I get multiple values from dropdown list and add them in lists? When I try to console selected values with JavaScript code, it prints correct values, but the problem is that, I can send them to controller and save them in db

Comment: `it prints correct values` you may need check if the key name of the form data if correct or not. Model Binding binds the model property by name. If you want to bind multiple Color selected to `List<ItemColors> Color`, you need pass with name like: `Color[index].ItemColor`. I have provided two ways to achieve your requirement. Pls check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model Binding binds the property by name. For your multiple selection, they match the model property in `List<ItemColors> Color`/`List<ItemSizes> Size`. So when you pass the selected value, the name should be something like:`Color[index].ItemColor`/`Size[index].ItemSize`.

Not sure how is your js code like, **no need add additional input elements** for the `select` in my demo.

```
<input id="otherMaterialInp" asp-for="@Model.MaterialType" class="form-control" style="display:none; margin-top:8px" placeholder="Enter Material Type" />
<input id="otherColorInp" asp-for="@Model.Color" class="form-control" style="display:none; margin-top:8px" placeholder="Enter Item Color" />
```

My whole working demo:

Model class:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
public class Item : BaseEntity
{
    [Display(Name = "Item Photo")]
    public string ItemPhoto { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Item Type")]
    public string ItemType { get; set; }      
    [Display(Name = "Item Category")]
    public string ItemCategory { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Item Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Item Colors")]
    public List<ItemColors> Color { get; set; } = new List<ItemColors>();
    [Display(Name = "Item Size")]
    public List<ItemSizes> Size { get; set; } = new List<ItemSizes>();
    [Display(Name = "Item Material Type")]
    public string MaterialType { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Designed For")]
    public string DesignedFor { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Item Price")]
    public double Price { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Item Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
public class ItemColors : BaseEntity
{
    public string ItemColor { get; set; }
    public int? ItemId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ItemId")]
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}
public class ItemSizes : BaseEntity
{
    public string ItemSize { get; set; }
    public int? ItemId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ItemId")]
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

Enum:

```
public enum MaterialType
{
    Meterial1,
    Meterial2,
    Meterial3
}
public enum ItemColor
{
    Red,
    Blue,
    Green
}
public enum DesignedFor
{
    Student,
    Teacher,
    Normal
}
```

View:

```
@model Item

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="CreateItem" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.ItemPhoto" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="file" name="ItemPhoto" class="form-control-file" onchange="SetValue(this)" />
                <input asp-for="@Model.ItemPhoto" hidden />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.ItemPhoto" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.DesignedFor" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="@Model.DesignedFor" class="form-control">
                    <option value="" selected>Select Designed For</option>
                    @foreach (var desigendFor in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DesignedFor)))
                    {
                        <option val="@desigendFor" value="@desigendFor.ToString()">@desigendFor</option>
                    }
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.DesignedFor" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.ItemCategory" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="@Model.ItemCategory" class="form-control">
                    <option value="Cat1">Cat1</option>
                    <option value="Cat2">Cat2</option>
                    <option value="Cat3">Cat3</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.ItemCategory" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.ItemType" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="@Model.ItemType" class="form-control">
                    <option value="Item1">Item1</option>
                    <option value="Item2">Item2</option>
                    <option value="Item3">Item3</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.ItemType" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.MaterialType" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="@Model.MaterialType" class="form-control">
                    <option value="" selected>Select Material Type</option>
                    @foreach (var materialType in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MaterialType)))
                    {
                        <option value="@materialType.ToString()">@materialType</option>
                    }
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
 <!-- useless input   -->
                @*<input id="otherMaterialInp" asp-for="@Model.MaterialType" class="form-control" style="display:none; margin-top:8px" placeholder="Enter Material Type" />*@
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.MaterialType" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Color" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="@Model.Color" multiple class="form-control">
                    @foreach (var color in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ItemColor)))
                    {
                        <option value="@color.ToString()">@color.ToString()</option>
                    }
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
     <!-- useless input   -->
                @*<input id="otherColorInp" asp-for="@Model.Color" class="form-control" style="display:none; margin-top:8px" placeholder="Enter Item Color" />*@
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Color" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Size" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="@Model.Size" multiple class="form-control">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Size" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Price" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.Price" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Price" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <textarea asp-for="@Model.Description" class="form-control"></textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">    
                              <!-- change here   -->
                <input type="button" onclick="Create()" value="Create" asp-for- class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS in my view:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        function SetValue(el) {
            $("input:text#ItemPhoto").val($(el).val());
        }
        function Create () {           
            var fdata = new FormData();
            var fileInput = $("input:file")[0];
            var file = fileInput.files[0];
            fdata.append("ItemPhoto", file);

            fdata.append($("textarea").attr("name"), $("textarea").val());

            $("form input[type='text']").each(function (x, y) {
                fdata.append($(y).attr("name"), $(y).val());
            });
            $('select:not([multiple]) >option:selected').each(function () {
                var name = $(this).parent("select").attr("name");
                console.log(name);
                fdata.append(name, $(this).val());                   
            });
            $('select#Color >option:selected').each(function (index, obj) {
                fdata.append("Color[" + index +"].ItemColor", $(this).val());
                console.log($(obj).val());
            });
            $('select#Size >option:selected').each(function (index, obj) {
                fdata.append("Size[" + index +"].ItemSize", $(this).val());
                console.log($(obj).val());
            }); 
            var options = {};
            options.type = "POST";
            options.url = "/Items/CreateItem";
            options.dataType = "JSON";
            options.contentType = false;   
            options.processData = false;    
            options.data = fdata;
            options.beforeSend = function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("RequestVerificationToken", $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
            };

            options.success = function (data) {
            };
            options.error = function (res) {
            };
            $.ajax(options);
        
        }
</script>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateItem(Item item,IFormFile ItemPhoto)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {  
       //be sure your wwwroot folder contains a folder named `assets`
       var path = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "assets", ItemPhoto.FileName);
       var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
       await ItemPhoto.CopyToAsync(stream);
        item.ItemPhoto = ItemPhoto.FileName;
        _context.Add(item);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(item);
}
```

Result:

[image]

---

**Another way is that just use form submit**, you need set parameters for the multiple selection. Make `<select asp-for="@Model.Color" multiple>` as an example, you need add a type `List<string>` parameter named `Color` in backend.

**Note: no need add the additional input for the multiple selection.**

Whole working demo:

View:

```
@model Item

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="CreateItem" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.ItemPhoto" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="file" name="ItemPhoto" class="form-control-file" onchange="SetValue(this)" />
                <input asp-for="@Model.ItemPhoto" hidden />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.ItemPhoto" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.DesignedFor" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="@Model.DesignedFor" class="form-control">
                    <option value="" selected>Select Designed For</option>
                    @foreach (var desigendFor in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DesignedFor)))
                    {
                        <option val="@desigendFor" value="@desigendFor.ToString()">@desigendFor</option>
                    }
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.DesignedFor" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.ItemCategory" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="@Model.ItemCategory" class="form-control">
                    <option value="Cat1">Cat1</option>
                    <option value="Cat2">Cat2</option>
                    <option value="Cat3">Cat3</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.ItemCategory" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.ItemType" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="@Model.ItemType" class="form-control">
                    <option value="Item1">Item1</option>
                    <option value="Item2">Item2</option>
                    <option value="Item3">Item3</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.ItemType" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.MaterialType" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="@Model.MaterialType" class="form-control">
                    <option value="" selected>Select Material Type</option>
                    @foreach (var materialType in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MaterialType)))
                    {
                        <option value="@materialType.ToString()">@materialType</option>
                    }
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
    <!-- useless input   -->
                @*<input id="otherMaterialInp" asp-for="@Model.MaterialType" class="form-control" style="display:none; margin-top:8px" placeholder="Enter Material Type" />*@
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.MaterialType" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Color" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="@Model.Color" multiple class="form-control">
                    @foreach (var color in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ItemColor)))
                    {
                        <option value="@color.ToString()">@color.ToString()</option>
                    }
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
     <!-- useless input   -->
                @*<input id="otherColorInp" asp-for="@Model.Color" class="form-control" style="display:none; margin-top:8px" placeholder="Enter Item Color" />*@
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Color" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Size" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="@Model.Size" multiple class="form-control">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Size" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Price" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.Price" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Price" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <textarea asp-for="@Model.Description" class="form-control"></textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" asp-for- class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS in View:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        function SetValue(el) {
            console.log($(el).val());
            $("input:text#ItemPhoto").val($(el).val());
        }       
</script>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateItem(Item item,IFormFile ItemPhoto,List<string> Color,List<string> Size)
{
    foreach(var c in Color)
    {
        item.Color.Add(new ItemColors() { ItemColor = c });
    }
    foreach (var s in Size)
    {
        item.Size.Add(new ItemSizes() { ItemSize = s });
    }
    //......
    return View(item);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: just wow bro, thank you very much for your answer and especially for time you spent on my problem <3

Comment: I have only one question, when i add list<string> color and size parameter to controller, should i type additional js code in order to send these data to controller? i am asking because without js code it doesn't work and i guess i should make ajax request and send data to controller right?

Comment: No need use additional  js. Just use form submit. Model binding allows `List<string> parameterName` to receive multiple same name data.

Comment: yes i got it, thamk you very much <3